# In Blazor, can I share user login across multiple apps?

Tags: html, .net, authentication, iis, blazor

I'm separating one super-large Blazor app (an English education site) into two separate solutions for independent development: the main educational site, and a second gaming app.

Given that the two are hosted as apps under the same IIS site, will they share their login credentials?  If not so by default, is there any way to achieve this?

Specifically, I want someone who is currently signed in under the main app to be able to navigate to the gaming section under the same credentials, but I want oustide users (who may  not even know about the educational site) to be able to register and login to the gaming app.

Both apps share the same SQL database, and use the default Blazor identity system.

Comment: Create a DUENDE (Identity Server) server. The template VS uses the same code but MS provide Admin screens for one application only.

Comment: So, if both apps use the existing default Identity system (scaffolded when I first made the site), they would not be able to share cookies / authentication?

Comment: Google oath makes this pretty easy too! You could implement your own `IDataStore` to save / share the credentials in your centralized database.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, guys, but I'm not looking to build a new membership system.  I want to know how I can use my existing default membership system across multiple apps. (in IIS, an app basically would be like site.com/app1, site.com/app2).  So I want users who log in to either app to be able to navigate to the other app with their existing authorization.  BUT. . . they will be separately running apps, i.e. I may restart or update either one independently without the other going down.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 if you use Entity framework integration you should be able to migrate the users. I have copied users from one database to another before. https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/data/ef/

Comment: @Bennyboy, did you find an answer? The best I could think of was to have an Authentication web API and call it from various Blazor Apps, meaning every app will have its own login page but will use the same membership system.

Comment: One option would be to make a cross-index table, and spoof a login.  In Middleware, you can get the current user's UserId / UserName, and then do a forced login using the other site's (different) credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can integrate with external authentication services. That will serve as centralized login service.

Azure B2C for example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-7.0

There are others services like aws aws cognito. Also you can create your own authentication service.

Comment: My site is on an Azure server, so seems like it should be easy.  But don't you have to pay a small for every single user ID?  What I would really like is to give all users a domain account: somebody@mysite.com.

Comment: In Azure B2C 50k active users/month are free and anyone can register/login with their own e-mail address. If you want everyone to have @mysite.com then you need to use Azure Active Directory, but the price is high (6$ per user / month).